# How does this beam splitter work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-computer

Did I draw this beam splitter diagram correctly? Two entangled light beams start at the lower corners of the square and travel along the line, colliding at the junction. What exactly happens at the junction? I don't understand what would happen because the photons collide and I'm not sure how to express which directions they go. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need another arrow on the top ones going out.

The bottom left beam is going to have a portion bent 90 degrees right by one diagonal, a portion bent 90 degrees left by the other diagonal, and a portion going straight through.

Same with the bottom right beam.

So bottom left and bottom right would have an arrow in and out. Top left and top right would both have two arrows out.